# C# JSON Deserialize into local variables

Tags: c#, json, deserialization

I have something like this:

```
public class MyClass_T
{

    public string filename;
    public string filename_txt;
    public int version = 1;
    public double A;
    public double B;
    ....and so on with about 100 more variables
}
```

I've written the data to a file in JSON format with

```
    public bool readFormatFile(string filename)
    {
        JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        serializer.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
            {
                using (JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
                {
                    serializer.Serialize(writer, this);
                }
            }
        }
     }
```

Now I want to deserialize it.  I know I can do this:

```
    public bool writeFormatFile(string filename)
    {
        MyClass_T MC = new MyClass_T();

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
            {
                JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                serializer.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
                serializer.MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore;
                MC = (MyClass_T)serializer.Deserialize(sr, typeof(MyClass_T));
            }
        }
     }
```

Note that readFormatFile and writeFormatFile are part of MyClass_T.  I need to get the values back into my local variables without having to do a bunch of

```
    filename = MC.filename;
    filename_txt = MC.filename_txt;
    version = MC.version;
    A = MC.A;
    B = MC.B;
    ...and so on for the 100 or so variables.
```

Thoughts and ideas on how to proceed on this?

Comment: Why do you need to move them to local vars?  They are quite usable in the tidy class object, no?

Comment: Instead of using a 'writeFormatFile' method, you could add a static method 'GetFormatFromFile' to the 'MyClass_T' class that returns the 'MyClass_T' instance that is returned  from the serializer. And then you could use that method instead of 'new' to instantiate a 'MyClass_T' instance that is populated with the information that was previously serialized to the file.

Comment: Thank you @JohanDonne.  Can you show me what that might look like in a few lines?  I'm a bit out of my league here....

Comment: And I need to move them because there is a ton of code already built around them being in the form they are that I don't want to have to modify and debug.

Comment: @ctc There is no way to make it any less tedious than copying them all one by one(I mean there is tuple deconstruction, but that will be just as ugly).  I would recommend refactoring the code using those locals to access it out of the object instead.  On an unrelated note: your readFormatFile and writeFormatFile seem to do the opposite of what they suggest from name, seeing as readFormatFile writes it to disk and writeFormatFile reads it from disk

Comment: @Dan Thank you.  I had a bad feeling that was the answer.  And yes you are correct in the above sample code about my read/write error.  I was copying and pasting portions of code to give a sample of what I was doing and grabbed the wrong lines when I did that.  No worries - the actual is correct! :)

Comment: Wait, what do you mean by "local variables" here?  "Local variables" usually refers to variables that are declared inside a method body somewhere.  But it sounds like you really mean *member fields* of an existing instance of a class.  If that is the case you could try using the `PopulateObject` method on the serializer instead of `Deserialize`.  I think that will do what you want.

Comment: @Brian: nice one. Didn't know about the PopulateObject method.

Answer (score 0):

Like many people have made clear, it is not a very good idea to deserialize a JSON object to local variables, however if you can not create a class for the object, you can use the `dynamic` object type, this will allow you to deserialize the JSON into an object whilst removing the need to add any strongly types models/classes.

all you need to do is cast the deserialized result to a `dynamic` as you would any other object, e.g.

`dynamic myObject = (dynamic)serializer.Deserialize(sr, typeof(dynamic));`

this will allow you to then access `myObject` as you would any other object e.g.

`myObject.filename` for example.

i would also like to reiterate that, you really should be using a class for this as it makes code a lot more predictable, maintainable and clean in general

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using an instance 'ReadFormatFile' method, you could add a static method 'ReadFormatFile' to the 'MyClass_T' class that returns the 'MyClass_T' instance that is returned from the serializer. And then you could use that method instead of calling the 'ReadFormatFile' method (or using 'new' to instantiate a 'MyClass_T' instance that is populated with the information that was previously serialized to the file).

Consider the following class:

```
class Demo
{
    public double A;
    public double B;

    public void WriteFormatFile(string filename)
    {
        JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        serializer.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Create, System.IO.FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
        {
            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
            {
                using (JsonWriter writer = new JsonTextWriter(sw))
                {
                    serializer.Serialize(writer, this);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static Demo ReadFormatFile(string filename)
    {


        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open, System.IO.FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        {
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs))
            {
                JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
                serializer.NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore;
                serializer.MissingMemberHandling = MissingMemberHandling.Ignore;
                return (Demo)serializer.Deserialize(sr, typeof(Demo));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and its use elsewhere:

```
const string filename = "demo.json";
        var d = new Demo();
        d.A = 2;
        d.B = 3;
        d.WriteFormatFile(filename);
        d.A = 4;
        // replace d.ReadFormatFile(filename); with the following line
        d = Demo.ReadFormatFile(filename);
        Console.WriteLine(d.A);
```

The output will be '2', the restored value for the 'A' field.

Comment: See Brian's comment above (about the PopulateObject method), which propably is a better fit for your situation...